# Why am I not able to install TensorFlow library in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, pip

I am not able to install TensorFlow library in the jupyter notebooks.

I tried to install the library using the pip keyword but it is not getting installed.[SS of the notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H60SC.png)

Comment: Can you please provide your configuration and the relevant error or error log? You can edit your question to do so. Thanks Varshita

Comment: As the image you provide says you may want to restart the kernel and then check what happens

Comment: Can you please provide the error messages within your question rather than an external image.

Comment: You will need to provide more context on this, but for now you can try running your Jupyter Notebook with administrator privileges. I belive it might permissions related issue.

Comment: For better experience, explicitly use the magic `%pip install` and `%conda install` commands inside a notebook. Also, because your screenshot shows you have anaconda around, **anaconda is now your main package manager**. Anything that there is a conda recipe for , then you should **preferably** use `%conda install` to install **always**. Your environments will be more robust and portable in the long run. Mixing and matching when you don't need to will only lead to issues. Of course, sometimes you have no choice but to use `%pip install` for those packages without a conda recipe.

Answer (score 0):

Try using conda to install this:

conda install TensorFlow or try:

pip3 install TensorFlow

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -2):

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2rQm.png)

I hope it helps to solve your problem!